# Multiuser application using flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I am working on one application which has multiple users. I have a list of resources, this list of resources are like a list of chocolates (only one and unique). Now, I am showing this chocolates on the home screen of all active users. Now, user can click on chocolate and it will be given to them. But, when this happens i want to refresh all logged in users so to ensure that no two users are having same chocolate.

I am using database trigger to monitor the change in DB. I am able to do that but my concern is how to refresh listView.

My Algorithm is as below:

1) Monitor changes in Database.
2) Get Fresh set of data.
3) *Update View*

I tried creating syncDatabaseFunction as below:

```
  Future syncDatabaseFunction() async {
    CollectionReference reference = Firestore.instance.collection('Chocolates');
    reference.snapshots().listen((querySnapshot){
      querySnapshot.documentChanges.forEach((change){
        print("Changed Chocolate");
        BackendOperations.getAllChocolates().then((value){

         var chocolateTemp = (value as List<ChocolateModel>)
              .where((element) => (element.chocolateColor == "Brown"))
              .toList();
          print("Count is ");
         return chocolateTemp;

        });
      });
    });
  }
```

For listview I am using futureBuilder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that if you use `StreamBuilder` you will solve the problem.
When a user remove or add a new Comment it show for all users.
`StreamBuilder` was made to do this, be a Observer of the Stream.

This is my code:

```
Widget getListComment() {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: Firestore.instance
          .collection('comments')
          .where('post', isEqualTo: postRef)
          .orderBy('createdAt', descending: true)
          .snapshots(),

      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ],
            );

          default:
            return new ListView(
              children:
                  snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                return CommentItem(
                  key: Key(document.documentID),
                  comment: Comment.fromDoc(document),
                  myUser: widget.myUser,
                );
              }).toList(),
            );
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

I receive comments from Firebase and show in a `ListView`, I think that is like your chocolates.