# Flutter/ Dart Users sharing same screen at the same time

Tags: flutter, dart, stream-builder, flutter-listview, flutter-futurebuilder

I am receiving data from an API and displaying it in a specific page. I want to display the data dynamically, that when an user selects an object from a list view builder, it refresh the database automatically and removes it from the other user's screen.
For that, I imagine *StreamBuilder* would be the best choice, based on this [Multiuser application using flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55542526/multiuser-application-using-flutter).
I Hope someone can help me on that :)

**Future:**

```
class OrdersBloc {
  Future<List<OrdersModel>> getOrders() async {
    try {
      WooCommerceAPI wooCommerceAPI = WooCommerceAPI(
        url: urlWC,
        consumerKey: consumerKeyWC,
        consumerSecret: consumerSecretWC,
      );

      List<OrdersModel> ordersList = [];
      var listOrders = await wooCommerceAPI.getAsync(statusProcessing);

      for (var item in listOrders) {
        ordersList.add(OrdersModel.fromJson(item));
      }

      return ordersList;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

**FutureBuilder:**

```
         FutureBuilder(
          future: OrdersBloc().getOrders(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
              case ConnectionState.done:
                return ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                  itemCount: snapshot.data != null ? snapshot.data.length : 0,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    OrdersModel orderItem = snapshot.data[index];
                    return Container(...);
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

To use a `StreamBuilder`, your data source must be a `Stream`, and to have a Stream as your data source your database should be a real-time database. You can't implement that feature with a database based on an HTTP request/response, your database should have a socket connection with all devices so it will be able to send data to all of them whenever the data are updated.